# Using usort for object sorting

Tags: php

I am trying to sort an object array by distance using usort. Here is my sort function:

```
private function sortDistance ($first, $next)
{
    $d1 = $this->searchDistance[$first->zip];
    $d2 = $this->searchDistance[$next->zip];

    if ($d1 == $d2) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($d1 > $d2) ? +1 : -1;
}
```

Here is where I am calling usort:

```
return usort($searchResults->limit('5', $start)->get()->result(), array("Search", "sortDistance"));
```

For some reason, when I print_r the returned result, its only printing 1. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, I am an idiot. Its returning 1 because usort completes. I need to return the same result after the sort.

Comment: Whoops! didn't see the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Returning usort is returning 1 because the usort function has completed [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). print_r() the array you just sorted, and you will see the sorted values :)

Working example:

```
$result = $searchResults->limit('5', $start)->get()->result();
usort($result, array("Search", "sortDistance"));
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your sort function static:

```
 private static function sortDistance ($first, $next){ ...
```

Also, this will only work for sorting inside the Search class where the method is defined since it is private.  To use  it in the child classes make it protected, for use anywhere make it public.

Alternately, if you want to method it non-static and you're inside an instance of a Search object, you could make the method non static and call it like this:

```
  return usort($searchResults->limit('5', $start)->get()->result(), 
                array($this,   "sortDistance"));
```

Comment: This will still return the return value of `usort` rather than the sorted array. See other answer